# new principled shader not working

Tags: materials

I've been using the new shadier in 2.79's test builds but a while ago it just stopped working. When I try to use an image the material just turns to a flat color. Any ideas as to why this is as I can see it loading properly on the side?
[image]

Comment: Have you UV-unwrapped the cube?

Comment: Yep that was it. I took a break for a bit and forgot that important detail. Thanks!